# Handling delete operation in express + pug template engine

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm learning express and have created a to-do list app in express with pug template engine. In this app, I can add and view to-dos. Now I want to add a delete functionality.

My pug code to render the to-do list is:

```
  ol
  each val in toDoList
    li= val.taskName
    a(class='button' href='/todos/'+val._id) delete
```

Here's my express code to handle the delete:

```
app.delete('/todos/:id', function(req, res){
    db.collection('todos').findOneAndDelete({id: req.params.id}, function(err, results) {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      res.redirect('/');
  });

});
```

I am getting this error `Cannot GET /todos/5e570f67ed9efba99c938719`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why you are getting the error:**
The link element: `a(class='button' href='/todos/'+val._id) delete`
is going to render a link element like this: `<a class='button' href='/todos/5e570f67ed9efba99c938719'>delete</a>`(assuming `val._id` is `5e570f67ed9efba99c938719`).

Clicking this link won't delete the todo but instead, take you to a page whose URL is something like this `/todos/5e570f67ed9efba99c938719` and this would cause the client app make a `GET` request to your server for that route. Since you do not have any route-handler matching the requested route from the client app in the server, you get the error: `Cannot GET /todos/5e570f67ed9efba99c938719.`

**The Fix**
To delete the todo, what you need to do is add an event listener to the link such that when you click it, instead of just redirecting you to some page, the handler attached to the event listener would be executed to reach out to your server and delete the todo. A sample implementation:

```
// Add some more properties to the delete button
a(class='button delete-todo' data-articleid=val._id href='/todos/'+val._id) delete
```

And in a `<script />` tag or a javascript file that would be loaded with the pug template, add this:

```
// SOURCE: https://github.com/elvc/node_express_pug_mongo/blob/master/public/js/main.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button.delete-todo').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.attr('data-articleid');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: '/todos/'+id,
      success: function (response){
        // Whatever you want to do after successful delete
        console.log(response);
        alert('Deleting article');
      },
      error: function(err){
        // Whatever you want to do after a failed delete
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```